# Autoregressive Process Question

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

May I know what $x,y,z$ in `ARProcess[x,{y},z]` mean?

```
ma = EstimatedProcess[detrend, ARProcess[1]]
(* Out: ARProcess[-1.14364*10^-13, {0.235799}, 0.00209441] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the manual for [`ARProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ARProcess.html)?

You have a numbers (not matrices), thus you need this and this rules:

> `ARProcess[{a1,…,ap},v]` represents a weakly stationary autoregressive process of order `p` with normal white noise variance `v`.
>
> `ARProcess[c,…]` represents an AR process with a constant `c`.

Thus, in your case you have an AR process of degree 1 with constant `c` equal to `-1.14364*10^-13` (zero means), coefficient of an AR process `0.235799` and a variance of residuals equal to `0.00209441`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{f = RandomFunction[ARProcess[x, {y}, z], {1, 10^2}]},
  ListPlot[SeedRandom[1234]; f,
      Filling -> Axis, 
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-0.5, 0.5}}]],
 {{x, -a}, -1, 1},
 {{y, b}, -3*b, 3*b},
 {{z, c}, $MinMachineNumber, 20*c}, 
 Initialization :> (a = 1.14364*10^-13; b = 0.235799; c = 0.00209441)]
```

[image]

`ARProcess[x, {y}, z]` represents a first order autoregressive process. If you play around with the `RandomFunction` defined by the process in the code above, you'll see that $x$ is a constant offset, $y$ is a process parameter, and $z$ represents the variance.

Comment: may I know the name of those?